# best way to remove "==" from random characters

Tags: php, encoding, base64

Why base64 ends with == ? Sometimes it ends with == in random characters.

I want to know how to remove those == or = from random characters. Which is the best and right way to remove these = from random characters?

Is this the best way to remove these == ?

```
str_replace("=","",$url)
```

Comment: `"=="`? Only one `=`

Comment: This question doesn't show much research effort. Both Google and the Stack Overflow search gave that duplicate as a first result when searching for your exact question title.

Comment: @GolezTrol I want to know the best way to remove these = from random characters?

Comment: @aldrin27 multiple "=="

Comment: You could try `preg_replace` function of PHP

Comment: @aldrin27 what about str_replace?

Comment: The question you orgininally asked has been asked before and already has an answer. If your question turns out to be different, please ask a new question, since it's hard to get enough votes to reopen your question.

Answer (score 2):

from Wikipedia

> An additional pad character is allocated which may be used to force
>   the encoded output into an integer multiple of 4 characters (or
>   equivalently when the unencoded binary text is not a multiple of 3
>   bytes) ; these padding characters must then be discarded when decoding
>   but still allow the calculation of the effective length of the
>   unencoded text, when its input binary length would not be a multiple
>   of 3 bytes (the last non-pad character is normally encoded so that the
>   last 6-bit block it represents will be zero-padded on its least
>   significant bits, at most two pad characters may occur at the end of
>   the encoded stream).